# I need to make a method which changes the status from false to true in my MongoDB C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, backend

I'm making a new website for internal use, where I'm making a method that changes the status from False to True in my MongoDB. Right now it says "IsClosed: false" if the request still have active access, when my Scheduler has detected that it went over the estimated time, it has to revoke his/her access and change the status from "False" to "True".

This is a new system that grants and revokes access to our databases and our servers, where our manager has to approve it, and then we have a scheduler that contains the rights to revoke and grant user access

```cs
 public static List<RequestAccess> CloseRequests(string requestId)
        {
            var filter = Builders<RequestAccess>.Filter;
            var idfilter = filter.Eq(x => x._id, ObjectId.Parse(requestId));
            var updater = Builders<RequestAccess>.Update;
            var isClosedUpdater = updater.Set(x => x.IsClosed, true);

            var list = RequestCollection.UpdateMany(idfilter, isClosedUpdater);

            return list;
        }
```

This is my guess on how to do it, but I'm not sure if it's correct or anything

Change status from False to True

Errors??: "Cannot convert expression type 'MongoDB.Driver.UpdateResult' to return type 'SystemCollections.Generic.List'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'd like to offer a solution using [MongoDB.Entities](https://github.com/dj-nitehawk/MongoDB.Entities) wrapper library. it is extremely simple to do stuff like this using it.

```
using MongoDB.Entities;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class RequestAccess : Entity
    {
        public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new DB("test");

            var result = CloseRequest("xxxxxxx");
        }

        public static RequestAccess CloseRequest(string requestId)
        {
            DB.Update<RequestAccess>()
              .Match(x => x.ID == requestId)
              .Set(x => x.IsClosed, true)
              .Execute();

            return DB.Find<RequestAccess>(requestId);
        }
    }
}
```

i think the code is self explanatory. if you need further clarification, let me know. good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found out why I couldn't get my code to run. I found out this -- https://pastebin.com/1rRbCfQR worked, and I found out why it "braked" it was because I was searching on the "IsClosed".. And I had to search on the "_id" and I tried that, and it worked.. But thanks a lot anyway for your answer :)